# Making logcheck react to something beyond just emailing me

Tags: linux, log-files, logging

Is there a way to make [logcheck](http://logcheck.org/) react to something?

For example, let's say I notice a certain pattern to some of the logs, and I think I could easily program some kind of parser to recognize, and then do something, e.g. add a rule to iptables.  Is there a way I can do this with logcheck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about log check, but if you set up Nagios monitoring you can also set up *Event Handlers*, which run scripts under certain conditions.  It would be pretty easy write a script that checks the logs for Nagios, alerts for certain text, and then Nagios would run the event handler script.  Although this is a bit involved, I think you might find many uses for Nagios. Here is the [documentation for Nagios event handlers](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/1_0/eventhandlers.html).

Another option might be to set up procmail and have it run scripts based on the email alert.  This is described in the [procmail faq](http://partmaps.org/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#rtfm) under "How can I run an arbitrary Perl or shell script on all or selected incoming mail? "

For logcheck itself, it looks like there is -o option:

"-o        STDOUT mode, not sending mail."

So you might be able to use that to pipe the output to a script that does that action you want if it finds the text, else it just sends the email as normal.  But I have never experminted with that myself.

Answer (score 1):

Hey-- old logcheck maintainer here.  There is no built in way to do this, though you could hack it with a pipe/grep like Kyle suggested.